# jQuery passing global variables into setInterval() loop

Tags: jquery, loops, setinterval

here's my code:

```
function flipCounter(){
    for(j=0; j<heights.length; j++){
        counter = 0;        
/*      setInterval(function(){   */
            if(counter < heights[j]){
                counter = counter + 1;
                $('.skill-table #bars').find('td').eq(j).find('label').html(counter+'%');
            }
/*      },10);                    */
    }
}
```

the goal is to update the value inside a label every 10milliseconds until the value reaches the one stored in the array **heights[]**. As you can see, I've tried with the setInterval loop, but doing so, heights went **undefined**

Whole the function could work with a while loop:

```
while(counter < heights[j]){
    counter = counter + 1;
    $('.skill-table #bars').find('td').eq(j).find('label').html(counter+'%');
}
```

omitting the **setIntveral** at all. But this way the value in the label changes instantly. But I was indeed trying to delaying it to 10ms. Adding a **setTimeout** in the while loop is no go.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure variable

```
function flipCounter(){
    for(j=0; j<heights.length; j++){
        (function(idx){
            var counter = 0;        
            setInterval(function(){   
                if(counter < heights[idx]){
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    $('.skill-table #bars').find('td').eq(idx).find('label').html(counter+'%');
                }

            },10);                    
        })(j)
    }
}
```